# Disable the centring image function in a slideshow plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I am using a slideshow plugin that centres the images in the browser. I need to disable this function so that the images in the slideshow stay fixed and do not move as the browser size changes. I have looked through the js file and the css but cannot figure out how to fix the image.

Please view this page that I am working on to see my problem: http://georgewoolfe.com/new-website/yogurt-line.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this in the script

```
// Adjust image when browser is resized
$(window).resize(function(){
    base.resizeNow();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I removed that from the script and it does keep the image in place now. However it always centres the image when you refresh, I want to control where the image is all the time, so I also need it to ignore the functions that are gathering the browser size and then centring the image??? Can you help?